# Unable to get property 'SPCascadeDropdowns' of undefined or null reference

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery, spservices

I am Implemented Drop down cascading in SharePoint online list.

I have used below code,its working in **Google Chrome** browser but it shows error in **IE** browser and **Firefox** browser

**Error:  Unable to get property 'SPCascadeDropdowns' of undefined or null reference**

```
  <script language="javascript" src="/sites/ABC/SiteAssets/jquery-1.11.1.js"     
  type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script language="javascript" src="/sites/ABC/SiteAssets/jquery.SPServices-0.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function() {
   $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
     relationshipList:"States",
     relationshipListParentColumn:"Country",
     relationshipListChildColumn:"Title",
     parentColumn:"Country",
     childColumn:"State",

   });

$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
   relationshipList:"Cities",
   relationshipListParentColumn:"State",
   relationshipListChildColumn:"Title",
   parentColumn:"State",
   childColumn:"City",

  });

});
```

Comment: Related? http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/162577/8992

Comment: Dylan , That's working for me.  
You save my day!